# Rabl 1+N Queries and slow view loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rabl

We have a Rabl view that's powered by a Rails action with nested children, in a structure like so:

```
:foo has many :bars
:bar has many :baz
```

Which means that our rabl view might look something like this:

```
collection @foo
attributes (#whatever)
child(:bar) {attributes :baz}
```

This works wonderfully, except for the fact that Rabl performs a new query to load each of the bar objects, as well as each of the baz objects (there are up to 7 baz objects). The query that generates the original collection takes less than 100ms to return, but the total rendering time takes upwards of 8 seconds, and includes about 30 additional queries per `foo` record. I've tried using the `includes` syntax to preload the associated rows so that Rabl wouldn't need to reload them, but it seems to just ignore the information that's sent along.

I'm looking for an idea as to how I can optimize this operation so that we can get the best possible performance out of this. I'm not quite sure what the right way to attack from here really is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your `includes` like? Is the server console showing prefetching of associations at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with an acceptable way to speed things up using Rabl, so I was forced to make this one endpoint build the response object by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this issue has been tackled here:

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/142#issuecomment-2969107

by using object false and assigning the object to an array like this:

```
object false
child @cars.to_a do
extends "api/v1/cars/car"
end
```

Comment: Looking into adding this. It looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this to work with our views (not sure why, but I couldn't get any data to display). Unfortunately, we're under a bit of a time crunch, so I ended up just having to build the hash that contained the response by hand for this one endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired extends command? check this link it will help you https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to [cache](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#caching) fragments.

Another way is to see why `includes` does not work. I had the impression that it works (since I use it in my codebase). Add your `includes` code and let's see if we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a direct relationship, i.e a "belongs to" relationship, there's a trick you can do to force the records to preload. In your controller you would write:

```
@foo = FooModel.all
@foo.bars.size
. . .
render 'foo/view'
```

Even if you have a nested relationship, this will work:

```
@foo = FooModel.all
@foo.bars.size
@foo.bars.bazzes.size
. . .
render 'foo/view'
```

The "size" method pre-loads all of the objects by their associations rather than delegating rabl to the individual queries.